# insert jquery js variable in Url.Route

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

This works fine, but consists hardcode in "url" section:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function aj() {
        var a = $('#price').val();
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Item/GetStatus?price=" + a,
            type: this.method,
            success: function (result) {
                $('#w').html(result);
            }
        });
        return false;
    }
</script>
```

This doesn't consist hadrcode, but it is not clear how to pass variable "a".

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function aj() {
        var a = $('#price').val();
        $.ajax({
            url: "@Url.RouteUrl(new {controller = "Item", 
                                     action = "Getstatus", 
                                     price = "a"})",
            type: this.method,
            success: function (result) {
                $('#w').html(result);
            }
        });
        return false;
    }
</script>
```

Using variable is not necessary. How can I pass variable? Maybe I use incorrect helper, or overload?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could ofcourse just do

```
url: "@Url.RouteUrl(new {controller = "Item", action = "Getstatus"})?price=" + a,
```

Comment: just add please "}" where you missed it.